# LaTeX (Custom Chapter Title)

Tags: titlesec

I have customize the chapter title. But, I want that the custom chapter title will not be set for all chapters. I want to set different chapter title styling for different chapter. Is it possible and if yes then please tell me how??

Comment: Yes. Can you show what you mean by supplying some code? A solution will most likely depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us what you have done (supply a MWE). I don't use `titlesec` but I think that after a `\titleformat` command subsequent titles follow that format until another `\titleformat` is issued to change the format. Roughly speaking like the following

```
...
\usepackage{titlesec}
\begin{document}
\chapter{...}% class style
...
\titleformat{...} % format 1
\chapter{...}% in format 1
...
\titleformat{...} % format 2
\chapter{...}% in format 2
```